# How to calculate the probabilty P(X=Y) given a joint (X,Y) pdf?

Tags: integration, limits, probability-distributions

I need to calculate the probability that $P(X = Y)$ knowing that
$$f(x,y) = 8xy, \quad \text{for x,y>0 and} \quad x^2 +y^2 \leq 1.$$

I know the area of integration is a 1/4 of the circle with the radius of 1. My approach would be transform $P(X = Y) = P(X-Y=0)$ and integrating the pdf from $0$ to $+ \infty$ for y and i don't know what boundries should have the integral for x, ie
$$P(X-Y=0) = \int_0^{+\infty} \int_?^? 8xy \quad dxdy. $$

Comment: If $\mu$ is absolutely continuous relative to $\lambda$ and $\lambda(A) = 0$ then $\mu(A) = 0$ (by definition). By definition, the measure associated with a density is absolutely continuous relative to Lebesgue measure. Any line has zero plane Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @WilliamM yes I know it should be zero in theorey but wanted to see it by calculating

Comment: If you insist in writing the integral, then $\int_0^1 dx \int_x^x f(x,y) dy = 0.$

Comment: @WilliamM. thanks! And if we would want to calculate P(x-y>0) ? How to find limits for this?

Comment: $\int_0^1 dx \int_0^x f(x,y) dy.$ (Just be careful with the other limit $y \leq \sqrt{1 - x^2}.$)

Comment: @WilliamM. Try a simple explanation. It’s not so turbulent.

Comment: $\LARGE 0$.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @FelixMarin I wrote a comment, not an answer. I did add an answer now. You can check it out too and comment there if you find anything interesting to point out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full solution.

You want to calculate $P(X = Y)$ and $P(X > Y).$ *By definition of density,* $f$ is the density of a random vector $(X,Y)$ in $\mathbf{R}^2$ if $P((X,Y) \in \mathrm{R}) = \int\limits_\mathrm{R} f$ for every Borel set $\mathrm{R}$ of $\mathbf{R}^2.$ Note that, *by convention,* $\{X = Y\}$ and $\{X > Y\}$ mean $\{(X, Y) \in \mathrm{D}\}$ and $\{(X, Y) \in \mathrm{B}\}$ where $\mathrm{D}$ is the "diagonal" of $\mathbf{R}^2,$ meaning the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $x = y$ runs through $\mathbf{R},$ and $\mathrm{B}$ is the region below the diagonal, that is the set of all $(x,y)$ such that $x > y.$ Therefore,
$$
P(X = Y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int\limits_x^x f = 0, \quad P(X > Y) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \int\limits_{-\infty}^x f.
$$
So far, this is true for *any* $f.$ Most densities used in practice, however, have the form $f = f \mathbf{1}_\mathrm{S},$ where $\mathbf{1}_\mathrm{S}$ is the indicator function of the region $\mathrm{S}$ (viz. the function that equals one on $\mathrm{S}$ and zero on the complement, sometimes called the *support* of the random variable) and $f > 0$ on $\mathrm{S}$. In this situation,
$$
P((X,Y) \in \mathrm{R}) = \int\limits_\mathrm{R} f = \int\limits_\mathrm{R} f\mathbf{1}_\mathrm{S} = \int\limits_{\mathrm{R} \cap \mathrm{S}} f.
$$
Then, you need to write $\mathrm{R} \cap \mathrm{S}$ in an familiar or integrable form. In general, we can only explicitly integrate (using the fundamental theorem of calculus), thanks to Tonelli's theorem (often misnomered Fubini's theorem) regions that take either of the following two forms: vertical lines of different heights,
$$
\mathrm{V} = \{(x, y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \mid a \leq x \leq b, u(x) \leq y \leq v(x)\}
$$
or horizontal lines of different widths,
$$
\mathrm{H} = \{(x, y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \mid a \leq y \leq b, u(y) \leq x \leq v(y)\}.
$$
Note that, Tonelli's theorem (iterated integration) gives
$$
\int\limits_\mathrm{V} f = \int\limits_a^b dx \int\limits_{u(x)}^{v(x)} f(x,y) dy, \quad \int\limits_\mathrm{H} f = \int\limits_a^b dy \int\limits_{u(y)}^{v(y)} f(x,y) dx.
$$

In your case,
$$
\mathrm{S} = \{(x,y) \in \mathbf{R}^2 \mid x, y > 0, x^2 + y^2 < 1\}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{S} &= \{(x, y) \mid x, y > 0, x > y, x^2 + y^2 < 1\} \\
&= \left\{(x,y) \middle| 0 < x < 1, 0 < y < \min\left(x, \sqrt{1 - x^2} \right) \right\}.
\end{align*}
$$
Whence,
$$
P(X > Y) = \int\limits_0^1 dx \int\limits_0^{\min\left(x, \sqrt{1-x^2}\right)} 8xy dy.
$$
Obviously, you need to find when the minimum in the inner integral is $x$ and when is $\sqrt{1 - x^2}.$ Note $x \leq \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ is equivalent to (assuming $x > 0$) $x \leq \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$ Therefore,
$$
P(X > Y) = \int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} dx \int\limits_0^x 8xy dy + \int\limits_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^1 dx \int\limits_0^{\sqrt{1 - x^2}} 8xy dy = \dfrac{1}{2}.
$$

**Addendum:** this is of course a nice exercise on understanding how to break down a probabiltiy density into integrable regions. However, there is a nicer approach. Note that $f(x,y) = f(y, x),$ so there is a symmetry in $f;$ by properties of the measure $P,$ we have
$$
1 = P(X < Y) + P(X = Y) + P(X > Y) = P(X < Y) + P(X > Y)
$$
and both of these sides are, therefore, the integral of $f$ over the same region, meaning that $1 = 2 P(X < Y) = 2 P(X > Y)$ and same result follows.